# アニメーションを順番にしたい

Tags: ios, objective-c

超初心者です。すみません。

複数のimageViewのアニメーションを順番に一つずつ動くようにしたいです。
現時点では指定した数のimageViewは落ちてきますが、すべて同時に落ちてきます。
@"アニメーション終了"のログも同時に出ます。

imageViewをfor文の中で配列に入れる必要があるのでしょうか。
よろしくお願いいたします。

```
-(IBAction)buttonPushed{

for(i = 0;i < repeatCount;i++){
    image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"img.png"];
    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:image];

    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(15+i*40, -150, 85, 150);
    [self.view addSubview:imageView];


    // アニメーション    
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f 
                          delay:0.1f
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^{
                         imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 550);

                     } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         NSLog(@"アニメーション終了");

                     }];

        usleep(500000);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`delay:`を使うのが楽だと思います。

```
// アニメーション
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f
                      delay:0.1f + 0.5f * i
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^{
                     imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 550);

                 } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     NSLog(@"アニメーション終了");

                 }];

//usleep(500000); 消しても良い
```

Answer (score -3):

iOSとiPhone/iPadは、マルチスレッドで動いています。アニメーションが（見た目）同時に動いてしまうというのは、for文のくり返し処理と、UIViewのアニメーションが、別スレッドで処理されていると、判断できるでしょう。`repeatCount`がどのくらいの大きさかわかりませんが、`10000`であっても、0.1秒かからないでしょう。

一定間隔で、アニメーションを開始するなら……`NSTimer`クラスを利用する。マルチスレッドを直接触る（`NSThread`クラス、GCD（Grand Central Dispach)など）ということも考えられますが、それなりの勉強が必要です。

```
usleep(500000);
```

これはなんでしょうか？「超初心者」の人が安心して使える関数なんでしょうか？いずれ、無視されてることは確実ですけど。

---

サンプルコードを載せておきます。
NSTimerを使った処理。

```
- (IBAction)startAnimation:(id)sender { // ボタンを押して開始。
    // タイマーを作って、開始。repeatsをYESにして、無限ループにする。
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 1.0 target: self selector: @selector(moveImage:) userInfo: nil repeats: YES];
}

- (void)moveImage: (NSTimer *)timer { // NSTimerが呼ぶセレクタ。
    // staticオプションをつけて、メソッド内で有効な変数とする。
    static int count = 0; // 繰り返しのカウンタ。
    static CGPoint imageCenter = {70.0, 70.0}; // imageViewの位置。
    if (count > 4) {
        count = 0;
        imageCenter = CGPointMake(70.0, 70.0);
        [timer invalidate]; // 5回繰り返したらタイマー停止。
        return;
    }

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: [UIImage imageNamed: @"image.png"]];
    imageView.center = imageCenter;
    [self.view addSubview: imageView];
    [UIView animateWithDuration: 3.0 delay: 0.0 options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations: ^ {
        imageView.center = CGPointMake(imageCenter.x, imageCenter.y + 200.0);
    } completion: NULL];
    count++; // カウンタ追加。
    imageCenter.x += 20.0; // imageViewの位置を右にずらす。
}
```

Comment: (1)の方のアニメーションメソッドの再帰呼び出しは、CAAnimationのdelegateのオーナーシップルールが通常と違う（delegateだけど強参照する）ということを知らない初心者が使うと簡単にメモリリークするバッドノウハウの一つなのでおすすめしない方が良いと思います。

Comment: @quesera2 ご指摘ありがとうございます。改善するまで(1)は消しておきます。