# Xcodeでアニメーションを連続して実行できません

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Xcodeで、数字が増える度に更新された数が上下に動くアニメーションを作っています。

http://qiita.com/noppefoxwolf/items/32530bb5f011ac2c9c91

こちらのサイトを参考に作りましたが、 
for文で0から100の数字を順にカウントすると、最初の0の次がfor文の最後の100になってしまい、 
アニメーションが0→100の一回しか行われません。

ログとブレークポイントで確認すると、カウントはしっかり0から100まで1ずつ増加していて、 
ループが終わった後に数字が更新されてアニメーションしています。

100回ループさせて順に数えたいのですが、どうしたら良いでしょうか？ 
よろしくお願いいたします。

```
-(void) viewDidLoad{
    label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    label.frame = CGRectMake(100, 190, 100, 50);
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"AppleGothic" size:22];
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"¥%d",count];
    [myView addSubview:label];

   for(count = 0;count < 100;count++){

        Anim = [CATransition animation];
        [Anim setType:kCATransitionMoveIn];
        [Anim setSubtype:kCATransitionFromBottom];
        [Anim setDuration:0.2f];
        [coinlabel.layer addAnimation:Anim forKey:nil];
        label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"¥%d",count];
    }
}
```

Comment: 重複候補: [アニメーションを順番にしたい](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/18040/%e3%82%a2%e3%83%8b%e3%83%a1%e3%83%bc%e3%82%b7%e3%83%a7%e3%83%b3%e3%82%92%e9%a0%86%e7%95%aa%e3%81%ab%e3%81%97%e3%81%9f%e3%81%84)

Comment: @kishikawa katsumi あちらは、UIViewのアニメーション、この質問はCAAnimationのアニメーションということで、質問の重複とはいえないのでは？

Comment: @Harawo それは一理あると思います。私も少し考えましたが、結局、根本的な原因は同じなので（ループが回った後に次のランループでアニメーションが実行される）、やはり重複でまとめる方がいいのではないかと思いました。

Comment: https://teratail.com/questions/20058 マルチポスト

Answer (score 1):

参考サイトとサンプルコードを拝見させていただきました。

まず、参考サイトでは一度のみの実行しか考慮しておらず、プログラムによる繰り返しを考慮したコードになっていません。

その前提でサンプルコードを見てみるとfor文で一気にアニメーションを登録しているため、同時に100個分のアニメーションが登録されてしまっています。
結果的に一番最後に登録したアニメーションのみ実行されてしまっています。

そのため、何らかの方法で**１つ前のアニメーションが終了してから次のアニメーションを登録する**ように実装する必要があります。

以下はサンプルコードを極力引き継いだ形での例です。

```
int _count = 0; //ラベルに表示する数字用の変数
int _maxCount = 100;    //カウントアップする上限値

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    label.frame = CGRectMake(100, 190, 100, 50);
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"AppleGothic" size:22];
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"¥%d",_count];
    [self.view addSubview:label];

    label.tag = 100;    //別メソッドで取り出すためのタグを設定

    [self addTransitionToLabel:label withCount:_count]; //アニメーションの追加
}

/*
 *  CAAnimation(CATransitionの親クラス)のデリゲートメソッド
 *  デリゲート先にこのクラスを指定したアニメーションが終了した際に呼び出される。
 */
- (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)anim finished:(BOOL)flag {
    UILabel *label = (UILabel*)[self.view viewWithTag:100]; //タグを指定して対象のラベルを取得

    //停止を検知したアニメーションがlabel.layerに追加したものかどうか判定する
    //（CATransitionは自動的にtransitionがキーとして割り当てられるため、
    //　transitionをキーにしてlabel.layerからアニメーションを取り出す）
    if (anim==[label.layer animationForKey:@"transition"]) {

        //label.layerから前回のアニメーションを削除する
        [label.layer removeAnimationForKey:@"transition"];

        _count++;   //ここでカウントをインクリメント

        if (_count>_maxCount) {
            //_maxCountまでアニメーションが終わったら次のアニメーションを追加せずメソッドを終える
            return;
        }

        //次回のアニメーションを登録する
        [self addTransitionToLabel:label withCount:_count];
    }
}

/*
 *  アニメーション登録部分を別メソッド化
 */
- (void)addTransitionToLabel:(UILabel*)label withCount:(int)count {
    CATransition *Anim = [CATransition animation];
    [Anim setType:kCATransitionMoveIn];
    [Anim setSubtype:kCATransitionFromBottom];
    [Anim setDuration:0.2f];

    [Anim setDelegate:self];   //CAAnimationのデリゲート先としてself(このクラス)を指定
    [Anim setRemovedOnCompletion:NO]; //animationDidStopで判定するため自動削除させないようにする

    [label.layer addAnimation:Anim forKey:nil];
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"¥%d",count];
}
```

この例では画面表示直後にアニメーションが実行されますが、`addTransitionToLabel:withCount:`を実行することで任意のタイミングで再度実行可能です。

*例示するためのコードなので、やるべきでない書き方をしている部分がいくつかあります。実際に利用される場合は適宜書き換えてください。*